# Question about study material

Tags: resource-recommendations

Is there much difference whether I use Halliday-Resnick Fundamentals of Physics 8th edition or 10th edition? If any significant differences, what are they?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is opinion-based and depends on the preparation of the student.

Comment: aren't all questions on resource materials opinion-based and dependant on the student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two editions is that the 10th edition includes updates and improvements to the text, as well as additional worked examples and problem sets and the most recent edition is most likely to introduce the most up-to-date information and resources.